# How to define range of x values in plotting in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to define range of x values appeared in plot in python. For example, here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(13)
ax1=plt.subplot(111)
x=[i for i in range(100)]
y=[i**2 for i in x]
ax1.plot(x,y)
```

However, I want to see in the graph x ranges from 0 to 60 and 80 to 100. How, I can do it in matplot. Actual, problem is more complicated, just removing data doesn't appear to be good solution. I want to change plot.

I tried ax1.set_xlim([0,60]) but want to see from 80 to 100 also.

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried. It is important to create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: so... where is your code?

Comment: plt.figure(12)
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
for T in Tave[:-2]:
    GI_d=np.diff(np.array(GI[T][1:]))
    GV_d=np.diff(np.array(GV[T][1:]))
    GR_d=list(GI_d/GV_d)
    plt.plot(GV[T][2:],GR_d,label='T='+str(T)+'K')
ax1.set_ylim([-0.1, 0.4])
ax1.set_xlim([-1400,-200]) # want to change this part [-1400,-200] to [200,1400] range
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Comment: This is my real code. By idea is to define the range of the x axis .

Comment: Thanks for comment.  minimal example is provided.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find these answers.